# Show objects and privileges affected by role [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, privileges

How to display objects and privileges that are affected by a specific role?

I have managed to display that information for the tables with this query:

```
SELECT PRIVILEGE, TABLE_NAME from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS WHERE ROLE='MYROLE';
```

My question is how to perform this query with all objects in the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, its ORACLE.

Comment: Try strart with select * from dict where lower(comments) like '%role%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object privileges granted by role:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'MYROLE';
```

System privileges granted by role

```
SELECT * FROM dba_sys_privs WHERE grantee = 'MYROLE';
```

other roles granted by role:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_role_privs WHERE grantee = 'MYROLE';
```